# MissingSchemaError for Mongoose's Populate Method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to work mongoose's populate but keep getting this error:

```
/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:625
throw new MongooseError.MissingSchemaError(name);
      ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Users".
```

My code simply experiments with the basic populate functionality. It looks like this:

I define the schemas:

```
var user = mongoose.Schema({
  userName: String 
});

var client = mongoose.Schema({
 fk_user: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' },
 name: String
});
```

I create the models:

```
var UserModel = mongoose.createConnection('localhost','fixDB').model('Users', user);
var ClientModel = mongoose.createConnection('localhost','fixDB').model('Clients', client);
```

I saved an instance:

```
var user1 = new UserModel({userName: 'issimo'});

user1.save(function(err){
 if (err) console.log(err);

  var client1 = new ClientModel({fk_user:user1._id,name:'co'});

  client1.save(function(err){
     if (err) console.log(err);
               console.log('done');
         })
});
```

So far so good. My db has both documents.

Now I use populate on my clients to discover the associated user's userName.

```
ClientModel.findOne().populate('fk_user').exec(function(err, c) {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
   console.log(c.fk_user.userName);
});
```

And I get the above error. I'm at a loss: I updated my mongoose, and tried many different permutations of the code - I'm guessing (and hoping) that I'm overlooking something pretty rudimentary. There are many SO questions that are very similar, but none of them fit precisely.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your models like this. They don't need anything to do with DB connections.

```
var UserModel = mongoose.model('Users', user);
var ClientModel = mongoose.model('Clients', client);
```

Comment: @Peter Lyons can you please explain a little bit, I am also stuck with same issue, but my models are in different fiels and Model operation to get the details are in different file!!